# Unable to center UIView inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having problems centering horizontally a view inside a UIPageViewController.

[image]

My ViewController contains a UIView with the following constraints:

- Height 400
- 20 Align Leading to SafeArea
- 20 Align Trailing to SafeArea
- Top Space to NavigationBar 10

Inside this view, I have a container view aligned 10 to top, bottom, left and right.
The ContainerView links to a UIPageViewController, as can be seen in the image above.
In interface builder I can see all elements centered properly.
However, if I run the app, I get this:

[image]

I've been wrapping my head around this for a few days now, without any luck.

I deleted every single view and added them again, deleted the UIPageViewController and created it again, no luck.

What's strange is that I never had any issues with UIPageViewControllers so far. In fact, I have another section like this in the app (different content) and there everything is OK.

Any suggestions on what I could be missing?

Comment: Just checking - what settings do you have set for page spacing and spine location?  Are you putting something in there that is shifting the placement of individual views within your pageViewController?

Comment: @creeperspeak page spacing is 0 and spine location is none.

Comment: You may have to show more code or give more details for us to be able to help.  Are you doing your layout constraints in code or in Interface Builder?  If you're doing programmatic constraints can you show that code, and where/when you are calling it?  FWIW you might get answers just by using the Debug View Hierarchy tool (in the bottom debug area menu).

Comment: @creeperspeak I'm doing my layout in interface builder. I tried doing them programmatically and changing them programmatically, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out but only after encountering a similar issue with some UITextFields and other UIViews.

It seams that myContainerView.frame.size.width returns the width of self.view.frame.size.width instead of what should return.

In this case, the leading position of the ContainerView (20, relatively to the Safe Area) + self.view.frame.size.width made the view to look uncentered.

So I had to do some math here to fix it, although it seems more like a hack than an actual fix.

```
let mainViewWidth: CGFloat! = self.view.frame.size.width
let externalConstraints: CGFloat = 10*4
let imageViewWidth: CGFloat! = mainViewWidth - externalConstraints
let titleLabelWidth: CGFloat! = mainViewWidth - externalConstraints
let textLabelWidth: CGFloat! = mainViewWidth - (externalConstraints + 20*2)
    
clIVPaceContentLeading.constant = 0.0
clIVPaceContentWidth.constant = imageViewWidth
    
clLBLPageContentTitleLeading.constant = 0.0
clLBLPageContentTitleWidth.constant = titleLabelWidth
    
clLBLPageContentTextLeading.constant = 20.0
clLBLPageContentTextWidth.constant = textLabelWidth
```

Anyone has any idea on why this is happening?